# AWS API gateway with STS and Custom Authenticator -- anyone with example with browser client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I'm haivng a hard time getting this one to work, and I'm wondering if anyone might have a working code example I can glean over.  Here's my requirement:

- One AWS Lambda function (let's called it BizFunction), fronted by AWS API Gateway, and configured with custom authorizer.
- Another AWS Lambda function (let's called it LoginFunction), also fronted by AWS API without any authorization.  During the login process, LoginFunction authenticates user's credential input against user database and, if verified, creates a Cognito identity with STS.  The credential, session token, etc. is then subsequently returned back to user's browser.

What I can't figure out is how to write the code to invoke BizFunction.  I'm using the generated client SDK as provided by AWS API Gateway and my custom authorizer gets the entire Authorization string of "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=..../2016..../eu-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;host;x-amz-date;x-api-key, Signature=.....".  But how do I convert that into a Cognito identity, and then subsequently identified the user?

My client is a browser, and most of the examples I found are mobile-based.  Does anyone have any working example or pointer on how I can proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to use custom authorizers with requests that are signed with AWS credentials. If you are signing the request to API Gateway using the session credentials, simply enable "AWS_IAM" authentication.

If you want to see the identity, these will be available as part of the [$context.identity variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference).

Comment: Thanks Bob! I'm still fairly new to AWS so at best I only partially understood your answer.

Comment: At this time I'm able to get things to work (more or less) with custom authorizer by sending the identity id (hashed) via HTTP header.  In order to do what you've mentioned, namely signing request with AWS credentials, is there any detailed documentation on this?  I've been reading through lots of stuff on docs.aws.amazon.com but none provides sufficient details for me.

Comment: But the same client code (minus the send-back of identity code) works with custom authorizer.  Thanks again for reading and any help you can offer.

Comment: @MikeLiu The request is signed by the SDK, that is the contents of the Authorization header. What I was trying to indicate is that you should not use a custom authorizer for this, but enable IAM authentication. Once you enable IAM authentication, API Gateway takes care of validating the authorization header.

Comment: Thanks @Bob Kinney.  I tried exactly what you said -- no more custom authorizer but just enabled AWS_IAM.  However now I'm getting 403: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://...' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403."  Prior to switching to AWS_IAM, I did not get this error.  Any idea how I can further investigate or debug this error?

Comment: @MikeLiu unfortunately there is a known issue that some CORS headers are not included on certain errors even if supplied in the API configuration. We are aware of the issue but I can't commit to a timeline to when this would be addressed.